# Agora web client SDK not returning a history messages as expected

Tags: laravel, agora

I have created 2 users and done some chat between these users, but when click on specific thread the messages isn't appearing in proper format it's showing all send and received in a same column.[image]

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with laravel? can you please clarify?

Comment: Basically we are using implementing agora in our Laravel project,